# CSS inheritance in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I'm getting started with Angular and I'm trying to figure out how the styles.scss file works with the individual css files in the component folders.  I know styles.scss gets loaded when the app bootstraps, I can see the appropriate styles where necessary, but we're also including another stylesheet at the top of it as such:

```
@import "./assets/styles/general-theme.css";
```

Furthere down in styles.scss I'm declaring a variable to hold the font we want to use:

```
$font-stack: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

And then using the * to add that font to each element:

```
* {
font-family: $font-stack;
}
```

And using it throughout styles.scss, which works, but it looks like I have to either declare another variable in the general-theme stylesheet or specify the font explicitly. I can't imagine we'll ever use more than one font, so I feel like this should work for what we're trying to do.  Does this look like a reasonable way to do this?

Comment: put the general theme import below the variable declaration and then you can use the variable inside general theme (if you turn it into an scss file too) - we usually put all out variables in a separate file which we import first so they are available for all other files

Comment: Man, that only makes sense.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

A general scss variable file can be use every where just need to **imported** before you  use any variable and it accessible in any scss file in your case as **@Pete** mention you just need to include the import statement before importing the theme

*styles.scss*

```
@import "./theme/_variables";
@import "./theme/_general-theme";
...
```

or another way is possible to put the import statement for the variables inside the theme file

*_general-theme.scss*

```
@import "_variables";
...
```

the main rule is to import _variables.scss file before you use any variables,even you can use _variables inside any component style file if it scss

*app.component.scss*

```
@import "../theme/_variables";

p {
  font-family: Lato;
  color:$s-color;
  text-shadow: $text-shadow;
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53816139)